# Mongodb Aggregator - Check if string contains digits or special chars

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo Aggregators to prepare queries.

I would like to check two things:

- If my string has digits (e.g. "Luk3 Sk1w8lk3r");
- If my string contains special characters (e.g. "L*ke Sk!w"lz")
- Or if contains both (e.g. "L0ke Sk!w0l'z8")

I am trying to use the $regex method but It seems I have to specify too many fields:

```
{ value: { $regex: "!" } }
```

This only finds strings that contains "!", but I would like to find strings that may (or may not) contains more special chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1.** If my string has digits (e.g. "Luk3 Sk1w8lk3r");

Your filter `{"value":{"$regex": "\d"}}`.

> **2.** If my string contains special characters (e.g. "L*ke Sk!w"lz")

> {"value":{"$regex": "[.*+?^${}()|][\]"}}

The regex can be written little differently (without using the escape `\` for all special characters):

`"[.*+?^${}()|\]\[\\]"`

You specify the escape `\` for `[`, `]` and `\`. Further, you can include other special characters like `!` and `'` within the regex.

> **3.** Or if contains both (e.g. "L0ke Sk!w0l'z8")

- "if contains both" - means the "AND" operation.
- "contains digits or special chars" - means the "OR" operation (from this post's title)"

Here are regex for both:

- To perform the "AND" operation, use this:
  `"(?=.*[.'!*+?^${}()|\]\[\\])(?=.*[0-9])"`
- To perform the "OR" operation, use this: `"[.'!*+?^${}()|\]\[\\]|\d"`

Comment: Thanks, that's a better solution indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround using **$match**:

1. if string contains digits:

> {"value":{"$regex": "\d"}}

2. if string contains special characters:

> {"value":{"$regex": "[\.\*\+\?\^\${}\(\)|\]\[\\]"}}

Appreciated every future improvement on these queries!